# Applying styles on ul li elements jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

Hi I have a json object with which I am creating unordered list of elements.It's pretty straightforward.

So far I have this simple script.

```
 var data_to_send = $("#form1>div").find('input[name = "txt1"]').val();
 var data = ["Argentina", "Uk", "USA"];
 var obj = $("#div1");
 obj.append("<ul class='outerul'>");
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    obj.append("<li class='outerclass'>" + value + " : " + index + "</li>");
 });
 obj.append("</ul>");

 $('ul.outerul').css('list-style-type', 'square'); ??How can I apply style here
```

Now I am trying to apply style to li element which I am not able.Also any idea how to toggle the elements on click.

Comment: add classes to list item and write your css in a seperate css file.

Comment: Instead of applying styling via JS, you should consider using CSS <style> or file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `li`s are added to `div` not `ul`. `obj` is the `#div1` element not the `ul.outerclass` element so the style applied to `ul.outerclass` is not getting applied to the `li`s added to `obj`

```js
//var data_to_send = $("#form1>div").find('input[name = "txt1"]').val();
var data = ["Argentina", "Uk", "USA"];
var $obj = $("#div1");
var $ul = $("<ul class='outerul'>").appendTo($obj);
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $ul.append("<li class='outerclass'>" + value + " : " + index + "</li>");
});

$('ul.outerul').css('list-style-type', 'square');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

---

But as a more appropriate solution use a class to style the elements

```js
//var data_to_send = $("#form1>div").find('input[name = "txt1"]').val();
var data = ["Argentina", "Uk", "USA"];
var $obj = $("#div1");
var $ul = $("<ul class='outerul'>").appendTo($obj);
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $ul.append("<li class='outerclass'>" + value + " : " + index + "</li>");
});
```

```css
.outerclass {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add/toggle css class on click you can add this at the end of your code:

```js
//var data_to_send = $("#form1>div").find('input[name = "txt1"]').val();
var data = ["Argentina", "Uk", "USA"];
var $obj = $("#div1");
var $ul = $("<ul class='outerul'>").appendTo($obj);
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $ul.append("<li class='outerclass'>" + value + " : " + index + "</li>");
});

$('ul.outerul').css('list-style-type', 'square');

$ul.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( 'redText');
});
```

```css
.redText {
 color: red; 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>

click on list to change color
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this in multiple ways using jQuery / CSS.

JQUERY Option:

```
$('ul li').css('list-style-type','square');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/vm0tjn6a/

CSS Option:

```
ul li { list-style-type: square; }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your JS

```
var data = ["Argentina", "Uk", "USA"];
 var obj = $("#div1");
 obj.append("<ul class='outerul'>");
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    obj.append("<li class='outerclass'>" + value + " : " + index + "</li>");
 });
 obj.append("</ul>");

 $('li.outerclass').css('list-style-type', 'square');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/hdmv5x22/1/)